# Could a rear center of gravity position cause an airliner to lose control when a pitch-up is commanded?

Tags: safety, af447-accident

Modern aircraft cruise with the center of gravity close to the most rearward position to minimise trim drag, usually achieved with fuel in the tail surfaces. This is transferred forward before or during descent for landing.

Is it feasible that unexpected nose-up inputs could lead to partial stall with the aerodynamic center moving rearward, aggravating the nose high attitude to cause mushing? This is my suggestion that might explain the loss of AF447.

Without ASI (pitot icing) a pilot without experience of this might not recognise the problem. Further, in that attitude elevators could be ineffective and fuel transfer too slow for recovery that way.

This was a serious problem with T-tails and caused accidents to DC9, Trident, BAC1-11 and Tomahawk aircraft; maybe others.

The only solutions were stall warning and stick pusher systems, apart from streaming the braking 'chute by an RAF Victor crew.

Comment: `explain the loss of AF447` - the loss is fully explained.  The only mystery is why the crew did what they did.

Comment: AF447 didn't have a loss of elevator authority. It just had bad elevator inputs (given to it by the crew.) Also, the ASIs were fully functional for the last roughly 5 minutes on AF447.

Comment: unless the speculation about AF447 is removed, to me this question should remain closed.

Comment: @Federico: Let us deal with his speculation in the answers. Closing the question just because it contains disprovable speculation is too much censorship for me!

Comment: @PeterKämpf That's a decent point. Speculation about incidents still under investigation [is explicitly off-topic here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but not questions about incidents whose investigations have reached their conclusions.

Comment: @reirab I would accept it if this was a question about the final report, not a speculation about a parallel universe with alternate reality.

Answer (score 3):

On virtually any swept-wing design, "wingtip stalls" are a danger. Most light aircraft are designed with a straight wing and a leading-edge contour such that the inside of the wing stalls first. This has two advantages for light craft; first, aileron control is available as long as possible into stall entry, allowing roll control and thus the ability to stay coordinated. Second, the departure of airflow over the top inside of the wing will reduce or eliminate the downwash of air over the horizontal stabilizer, which normally corrects for a slight nose-heavy CG. With the balancing force gone, the normal response of the aircraft will be to nose down, restoring a lower AOA and building forward airspeed to let the pilot recover quickly.

With a swept wing as is seen on modern jet airliners, the wingtips tend to stall first instead, because the airflow over the swept wing lowers the stagnation point and thus the effective angle of attack of rearward sections of the wing, so the wingtips at the rear will exceed the critical AOA first.

When the wingtip stalls first on a swept wing, two things happen. First, aileron control is severely affected, making it harder to stay wings-level and avoid entering a slip or even a spin. Second, the center of lift from the unstalled portion of the wing moves forward, placing the CG further behind it. An aft CG works against pilot efforts to nose the aircraft back down to recover, and in an uncoordinated stall the aft CG will keep the tail of the airplane "outwards" from the center of the spin, hindering or preventing efforts to cancel out the rotation with the rudder as the vertical stabilizer will be stalled due to the extreme "sideslip".

This is a potential problem in any airliner, where the weight is distributed along the majority of the fuselage. Any significant deviation from mean values for per-passenger or per-bag weights can place the CG too far aft. Tail trim tanks can further exacerbate this.

However, Air France 447's crash, in my amateur analysis, was not caused by trim characteristics. It was primarily caused by the pitot tube icing. This had several detrimental effects on the flight crew's situational awareness:

- The disagreement of the plane's two pitot-static systems cause the flight director to unexpectedly disengage the autopilot, setting the flight crew on their heels.
- This same disagreement in the pitot-static data also caused the flight director to switch from "normal law" to "alternate law 2" which among other things disabled roll and pitch/AOA limiters, as the data used to calculate those limits is no longer reliable.
- Lastly, the lack of reliable pitot-static data was reflected in cockpit instrument displays. We don't know exactly what they saw because information on the status of the right side pitot system is unavailable (it was not recorded by the black boxes). However, we do know the disagreement of data caused the red-flagging of practically all information reliant on such data, including the airspeed and altimeter tapes, the flight director, velocity vector, and all secondary indicators including AOA readouts, the stall horn, etc. The flight crew would have been totally reliant on external visible references to determine the aircraft was stalled.

A secondary instrumental cause was the stall indicator system itself. Counter-intuitively, the stall warning was issued when the aircraft was nosed down, and stopped when the aircraft nosed up. This was due to the flight computer treating the extreme AOA calculations (in excess of 40 degrees) as unreliable. Nosing down brought the AOA back into the "reliable" band, but the resulting alarms were counter-intuitive to the pilots; applying a control input and hearing an audible warning is usually a signal to back off that control input.

Finally, the flight crew themselves demonstrated a lack of familiarity with the behavior of the aircraft in exceptional circumstances; the loss of pitch/roll limiters and the counter-intuitive stall horn behavior caused the flight crew, in the absence of the captain, to make a series of critical and ultimately fatal overcorrections and inactions.

Comment: Don't forget the middle part where the pilot flying botched the unreliable airspeed procedure. The procedure calls for maintaining certain fixed pitch and maintaining altitude with thrust, but the pilot let it climb which is how it got stalled.

Comment: Thanks for that, Keith S. I agree totally with what you say. My personal opinion (for what it's worth after 60+ years in aviation) is that aft CG limits control in some circumstances. Tip stall with swept wings aggravates the situation.

Comment: `Finally, the flight crew themselves demonstrated a lack of familiarity with the behavior of the aircraft in exceptional circumstances` Although all pilots are trained to handle stalls I would contend that few have experienced an actual stall in an airliner. Fewer yet have experienced a high altitude, high mach stall in imc. The pf apparently mistook the stall buffeting for overspeed buffeting as he referred a couple of times to a "crazy speed." But obviously as @JanHudec said, they didn't follow the procedures or they would never have stalled in the first place.

Comment: I was mainly talking about the backup flight computer modes. With most of the limiters disabled, the aircraft accepted input it would have otherwise rejected, and became much more sensitive to said input which kept the pilot occupied keeping her level while not paying attention to other elements of her flight envelope.

Comment: @KeithS The pilots weren't keeping it level, though. And all of the flight deck instruments were fully operational and indicating correctly for the last 4 minutes of flight; the pitot tubes had cleared of ice. Furthermore, airliners have multiple sources of speed information. While GPS-indicated speed isn't equal to airspeed, when it says you're moving at **60 knots**, you can generally assume that the wind around you isn't Mach 0.9 and, thus, you aren't supersonic. More information is available in [a translation of the CVR annotated with FDR data](http://goo.gl/q6rV6K/).